# App returns false as value instead of number

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm making a shopping cart application with react on the front end, redux for state management and firebase on the back end. The app is set up so you have to be logged in, in order to shop so each cart is specific to a uid that firebase provides with its authentication system.

This is the structure that I have to account for item quantity:

[image]

It takes the path of `users/uid/cart`. The logic is that on item add, I push the items id to the `ids` array, and set the `quantity` to be that of the item quantity in the cart. The quantity structure looks like this:

`quantity: {
  1 (item id): 2 (quantity) 
}`

But as you can see in the snippet, when there is no items added to the cart, the quantity gets set to false instead of an integer. However, on the second add, it works as it's supposed to but it doesn't reflect the previous add to the cart. So if I initially added 2 and then added 1 after that, it would total the quantity to 1 when it should be 3.

```
database
  .ref(`users/${uid}/cart/quantity`)
  .transaction(data => {
    return data != null && {
      ...data,
      [item.id]: value
    }
  })
```

Above is my add to cart quantity action

```
case ADD_TO_CART:
  return {
    ...state,
    ids: [...state.ids, action.payload.id],
    quantity: {
      ...state.quantity,
      [action.payload.id]: state.quantity[action.payload.id] + action.payload.value
    }
  }
```

Above is my add to cart reducer

Answer (score 1):

The first time a transaction handler function executes, you can expect it to receive a null value.  Your code needs to handle this.  Subsequent invocations of the handler function will receive the current value from the database.

In your particular case when your transaction handler receives a null value, it returns null, since `data != null` evaluates false, and the next boolean AND is short-circuited.  You need to do something different in the initial case that `data` is null, perhaps write a quantity of 0.